# update an observable collection when a model value is changed

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am writing an ingredients calculator for my recipe application that takes a value from a picker and alters the ingredient amount in an ObservableCollection to the number of people that has been selected by the user. Debugging has shown that the code behind works fine, but the observable collection doesn't update the UI with the new values. please help.

```
namespace SQLiteListView.Models
{
    public class Ingredients : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // primary key
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int IngredientsId { get; set; }

        // other attributes
        private string _ingredientsName { get; set; }
        private double _ammount { get; set; }
        private string _units { get; set; }

        public string IngredientsName
        {
            get { return _ingredientsName; }
            set
            {
                _ingredientsName = value;
                OnPropertyChange("IngredientsName");
            }
        }
        public double Ammount
        {
            get { return _ammount; }
            set
            {
                _ammount = value;
                OnPropertyChange("ammount");
            }
        }
        public string Units
        {
            get { return _units; }
            set
            {
                _units = value;
                OnPropertyChange("Units");
            }
        }
        public int RecipeID
        {
            get { return _recipeID; }
            set
            {
                _recipeID = value;
                OnPropertyChange("RecipeID");
            }
        }

        // specify the foreign key
        [ForeignKey(typeof(Recipe))]
        public int _recipeID { get; set; }

        // many to one relationship with recipe
        [ManyToOne]
        public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

ViewModel

```
private PickerNo _selectedPicker { get; set; }

public PickerNo SelectedPicker
{
    get { return _selectedPicker; }
    set
    {
        _selectedPicker = value;
        IngredientsCalculator();
    }
}

   void IngredientsCalculator()
{
    var ingredients = new ObservableCollection<Ingredients>();
    foreach (Ingredients i in IngredientsList)
    {
        i.Ammount = (i.Ammount / Recipe.Serves) * SelectedPicker.NumberOfPeople;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
}
```

Comment: you are calling IngredientsList.Clear();, then iterating over IngredientsList which you just emptied.  I think you need to check that logic first.

Comment: Updated it but it still doesn't work

Comment: Your casing is also wrong in OnPropertyChanged(“amount”)

Comment: ok So how do I cast the amount correctly, do I create another OnProperty changed method for the double

Comment: No bindings are changed? Or just some fields?

Comment: oh I tested it with the Units and they change so the model does update the view when elements are changed. however amount is stored as a double so PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)) won't update. as Jason has said the casting it wrong.

Comment: casing, not casting.  "ammount" should be "Ammount"